# How to convert integer to string with plus and minus

Tags: c

I need to get an integer form the user and put the number in array of chars with "+" or "-"
and it print only + and not - if the number is under zero, and it not print the numbers that the user put at all
if can someone tell me what is the problem in my code?
Thank you

```
int main()
{
    int number = 0, i = 0;
    char numberArray[MAX_LEN] = {0};
    int length = 0;
    int save = 0;
    int j = 0;
    printf("Enter num: ");
    scanf("%c", &number);
    if(number >= 0)
    {
        numberArray[i] = '+';
    }
    else
    {
        numberArray[i] = '-';
    }
    save = number;
    length = findLength(number);
    number = save;
    j = length;
    for(i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    {
        numberArray[j] = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        j--;
    }
    printf("%s", numberArray);
}
int findLength(int number)
{
    int length = 0;
    while(number > 0)
    {
        number /= 10;
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

Comment: You are reading with %c, that will read just one digit

Comment: @MEDLDN `itoa` is not standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(void)
{
    int number;
    char number_str[10];
    scanf("%d", &number);
    sprintf(number_str, "%+d", number);
    printf("%s\n", number_str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read your binary integer:

```
printf("Enter num: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
```

To print with +/-:

```
printf ("%+d\n", number);
```

To write the formatted integer to a string:

```
sprintf (numberArray, "%+d\n", number);
```

Here is a good reference for printf format strings:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: where does it save in a char array?

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%c", &number);
```

will give you the ASCII value of one char given in the input, that's why the numbers that printed aren't those you write.

you should change it to

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

this way it will get the right input

Answer (score 0):

```
if (number < 0) {
    printf("%d", -number);
} else {
    printf("+%d", number);
}
```

should suffice.  Let the standard library routines do their work.